# Why doesn't my JSF example work?

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, wildfly

I'm watching a tutorial about "Dynamic web applications with JSF" and have problems although I have the same code like the tutor. His example works fine.

I think I have several problems. The biggest problem is, that my JSF example doesn't work and I always have to restart eclipse if I change my code. Full publish doesn't work.

#### Console output

```
23:18:14,562 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.4.3.Final
23:18:14,695 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
23:18:14,747 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 9.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.1.Final) starting
23:18:15,417 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'enabled' in the resource at address '/subsystem=datasources/data-source=ExampleDS' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
23:18:15,418 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 8) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'job-repository-type' in the resource at address '/subsystem=batch' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
23:18:15,435 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0015: Re-attempting failed deployment JSF_Contacts.war
23:18:15,440 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found JSF_Contacts.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called JSF_Contacts.war.dodeploy
23:18:15,455 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
23:18:15,466 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-4) XNIO version 3.3.1.Final
23:18:15,472 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-4) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.1.Final
23:18:15,501 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
23:18:15,501 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
23:18:15,502 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
23:18:15,505 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
23:18:15,512 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.2.Final
23:18:15,511 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 16 core threads with 128 task threads based on your 8 available processors
23:18:15,514 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
23:18:15,547 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
23:18:15,547 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.2.4.Final)
23:18:15,551 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.2.9.Final starting
23:18:15,564 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
23:18:15,565 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.2.9.Final starting
23:18:15,571 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
23:18:15,571 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
23:18:15,570 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
23:18:15,697 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path C:\wildfly-9.0.1.Final/welcome-content
23:18:15,731 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.9.Final
23:18:15,762 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
23:18:15,768 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
23:18:15,913 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
23:18:16,034 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\wildfly-9.0.1.Final\standalone\deployments
23:18:16,036 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "JSF_Contacts.war" (runtime-name: "JSF_Contacts.war")
23:18:16,190 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 5.0.0.Final
23:18:16,211 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
23:18:16,223 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: WFLYSRV0083: Failed to start the http-interface service
    at org.jboss.as.server.mgmt.UndertowHttpManagementService.start(UndertowHttpManagementService.java:269)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.ManagementHttpServer.start(ManagementHttpServer.java:160)
    at org.jboss.as.server.mgmt.UndertowHttpManagementService.start(UndertowHttpManagementService.java:235)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:437)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:429)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioXnioWorker.createTcpConnectionServer(NioXnioWorker.java:182)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker.createStreamConnectionServer(XnioWorker.java:243)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.ManagementHttpServer.start(ManagementHttpServer.java:147)
    ... 6 more

23:18:16,339 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment JSF_Contacts.war
23:18:16,385 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-3) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.3.Final
23:18:16,520 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYWELD0006: Starting Services for CDI deployment: JSF_Contacts.war
23:18:16,540 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-8) WELD-000900: 2.2.14 (Final)
23:18:16,561 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYWELD0009: Starting weld service for deployment JSF_Contacts.war
23:18:17,198 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type SalutationHandler with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private training.data.ContactData.salutationHandler
  at training.data.ContactData.salutationHandler(ContactData.java:0)

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:359)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:281)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:155)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:518)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    ... 3 more

23:18:17,201 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("management-interface" => "http-interface")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: WFLYSRV0083: Failed to start the http-interface service
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind"}}
23:18:17,202 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "JSF_Contacts.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"JSF_Contacts.war\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"JSF_Contacts.war\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type SalutationHandler with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private training.data.ContactData.salutationHandler
  at training.data.ContactData.salutationHandler(ContactData.java:0)
"}}
23:18:17,224 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "JSF_Contacts.war" (runtime-name : "JSF_Contacts.war")
23:18:17,225 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
      service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: WFLYSRV0083: Failed to start the http-interface service

23:18:17,299 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0063: Http management interface is not enabled
23:18:17,300 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0054: Admin console is not enabled
23:18:17,300 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 9.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.1.Final) started (with errors) in 2915ms - Started 274 of 478 services (21 services failed or missing dependencies, 221 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
23:18:17,319 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYWELD0010: Stopping weld service for deployment JSF_Contacts.war
23:18:17,336 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment JSF_Contacts.war (runtime-name: JSF_Contacts.war) in 18ms
23:18:17,367 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0009: Undeployed "JSF_Contacts.war" (runtime-name: "JSF_Contacts.war")
23:18:17,368 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".WeldBootstrapService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".CdiValidatorFactoryService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".WeldStartService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./JSF_Contacts.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".CdiValidatorFactoryService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./JSF_Contacts.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./JSF_Contacts] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./JSF_Contacts.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./JSF_Contacts.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./JSF_Contacts.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./JSF_Contacts.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./JSF_Contacts.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./JSF_Contacts.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".ee.ComponentRegistry (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./JSF_Contacts.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".jndiDependencyService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START, service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START, service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START, service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".START, WFLYCTL0208: ... and 3 more ] 
      service jboss.server.global-request-controller.control-point."JSF_Contacts.war".undertow (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./JSF_Contacts.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./JSF_Contacts (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./JSF_Contacts.codec (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./JSF_Contacts.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./JSF_Contacts.session (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./JSF_Contacts.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."JSF_Contacts.war".WeldStartService
      service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: WFLYSRV0083: Failed to start the http-interface service

23:18:22,242 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found JSF_Contacts.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called JSF_Contacts.war.dodeploy
```

#### ContactData.java

```java
package training.data;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class ContactData implements Serializable {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private String message;
    private String salutation;

    @Inject
    private SalutationHandler salutationHandler;

    @PostConstruct
    private void initialize() {
        salutation = salutationHandler.getSalutations().get(0);
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getSalutation() {
        return salutation;
    }

    public void setSalutation(String salutation) {
        this.salutation = salutation;
    }

}
```

#### ContactsController.java

```java
package training.data;

import javax.enterprise.context.Dependent;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@Dependent
public class ContactsController {

    public String showData() {
        return "data";
    }

    public String inputData() {
        return "index";
    }

}
```

#### index.xhtml

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" />

</h:head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Kontakt</h1>
            <div>Bitte füllen Sie das Formular vollständig aus!</div>
        </div>

        <h:form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <h:outputLabel value="Andrede" for="salutation" />
                <h:selecOneMenu value="#{contactData.salutation}" id="salutation"
                    styleClass="form-control">
                    <f:selectItems value="#salutationHandler.salutations" />
                </h:selecOneMenu>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <h:outputLabel value="Ihr Nachname" for="lastName" />
                <h:inputText value="#{contactData.lastName}" id="lastName"
                    styleClass="form-control" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Ihr Vorname</label>
                <h:inputText value="#{contactData.firstName}"
                    styleClass="form-control" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Ihre E-Mail</label>
                <h:inputText value="#{contactData.email}" styleClass="form-control" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Phone</label>
                <h:inputText value="#{contactData.phone}" styleClass="form-control" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Ihre Nachricht</label>
                <h:inputTextarea value="#{contactData.message}" rows="7"
                    styleClass="form-control" />
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h:commandButton action="#{contactsController.showData()}"
                        value="Absenden" styleClass="btn btn-success" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

## Edit

#### Solution

The cause was a wrong import. I have to import

```
javax.ejb.Singleton;
```

instead of

```
javax.inject.Singleton;
```

Comment: Please don't ask the same question over and over. All that JSF code is irrelevant. The server wasn't even been able to execute it. You have just a problem in the configuration of your development environment.

Comment: No, I don't have just a problem in my config.

Answer (score 1):

Read the stacktrace carefully... especially the first trace and the *caused by* messages. You will see that : `java.net.BindException: Address already in use`.

What does it means ? It means that during startup, jboss try to start a service and this service needs to use a port, but unfortunately, on your computer this port is already used by some process.

According your comments (i.e. "need to restart eclipse"), it seems that this process is probably a previous instance of jboss. Take a look at what's going on when you stop JBoss... there must something wrong there because it doesn't stop properly (i.e. there is still *something* running and the required port is not released)

Comment: I solved this exception, but the others are left.

Answer (score 1):

JBOSS is trying to use a port in your PC is already in use. Check in your logs for: “**Caused by: java.net.BindException**: **Address already in use: bind**”

Check the port JBOSS is using and then you can check if this port is being use for any other application, it could be another instance of JBOSS but can be any other application too.

Normally JBOSS use **8080** for HTTP but there is few more ports that are using for other protocols and management that JBOSS need, using the command netstat you can check what other app is using those ports, for example (for 8080 port) you can use the command:

**netstat -aon | findstr :8080**

If you want to do a quick test you can pass this parameter to JBOSS “**-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=2000**” this will increase all the ports JBOSS use by 2000 (or any other value), then for example if your app was running in "**localhost:8080/your-context**" now will be "**localhost:10080/your-context**"

Good luck ;)

Comment: Thanks for your advice with "-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=2000". Now I can see that eclipse itself uses port 8080. I don't know for what. :D

Comment: But the other exceptions are present.

Comment: Can you put the exceptions you have now?

Comment: Seems like you have a problem also with CDI "**Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type SalutationHandler with qualifiers @Default**", sometimes this happen for a wrong locations of the **beans.xml** file or not **beans.xml** file at all. You should have this file in your META-INF folder for each of the libraries where you expect CDI to do introspection